# Is it correct that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty f(n)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty g(n) \implies f(n)=g(n)$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Is it correct that
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty f(n)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty g(n) \implies f(n)=g(n)$$
when the series are converging?

I know that this is false when the series are finite, but is it true when the series are infinite?

Comment: What do you mean by "this is false when the series are finite"?

Comment: If the summation is finite i.e. $n\in\{1,2,\cdots,N\}$ then the sums as written compute to $Na=Nb\implies a=b$.

Comment: Consider $1/2 + 1/4 + 1/8 + 1/16 +\ldots$ versus $1/4 + 1/2 + 1/8 + 1/16 + \ldots$.

Comment: I mean that
$$\sum_{n=1}^m a=\sum_{n=1}^m b \not\implies a=b$$

Comment: If the things being summed are literally meant to have no subscripts, then the series converge only when $a = b = 0$, so they are equal. :) But if you meant $\sum_n a_n = \sum_n b_n$, then the conclusion is false.

Comment: $a$ and$b$ are both functions of $n$

Comment: Ohh...good point. I figured it was meant to indicate $\{a_n\}_{n=1}^\infty = \{b_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$, i.e., equality of sequences...but maybe not.

Comment: If $a$ and $b$ are functions of $n$, the the conclusion is false, as my example, and Morgan Roger's note (finite series can be made infinite) both show.

Comment: This is the second time a question I've answered and considered very clear has been put on hold for being unclear.  LOL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

False.  Counterexample:  $f(n) = \dfrac{1}{n^2}$ and $g(n) = \dfrac{15}{\pi^2n^4}$.

\begin{align}
  \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{n^2} &= \frac{\pi^2}{6}\\[0.3cm]
  \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \frac{15}{\pi^2n^4} &= \frac{15}{\pi^2} \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{n^4}\\[0.3cm]
    &= \frac{15}{\pi^2} \cdot \frac{\pi^4}{90}\\[0.3cm]
    &= \frac{\pi^2}{6}
\end{align}